# using javascript in C#

Tags: c#, javascript

i claim my variable with javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">{
            function choose(x) 
                this.x=x;

            }
            var x= document.getElementById("Select1").selectedIndex;
```

i want to use this x variable in my C# code

```
<%SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
param.Value =(i want to write x right here) how???????????%>
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way to communicate between the client (JavaScript) and the server (C#) is to do a form submit or to use an Ajax call. So let's assume you'll want to send the value of the JavaScript variable to the server when the user submits. In that case you'll have to store the value of that variable inside a Hidden Field